# obtain photos from facebook developer test user

Tags: facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm a newbie at this into my third hour.
I'm trying to retrieve photos from my facebook test user.

Photos have been posted.
user_photos have been granted in the access_token.

I used the api like so:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=XXXXX
but the api returns an empty json with field 'data'.

if anyone is interested the test account is dave_qdoryet_ricesky@tfbnw.net/davericesky

Is there something I'm missing/did not yet check?

Comment: Well, it says in the error message you posted that the authorization failed. Have you checked upon that?

Comment: well there is no error message.

Comment: This is returned:{
   "data": [
      
   ]
}